# Obj-C, pass reference to self to a C function

Tags: objective-c, c

In my app, I have some C code that does some low level work, and needs to notify an Objective-C instance when a certain event occurs. The C function that does that low level work takes a void * to the context along with a pointer to a callback function. Then the worker calls the callback function and passes the context to it as well.

What I am trying to do is to pass a reference to "self" to that worker function, but so far I haven't had much success.

I tried 
dumb casting: `(void *) self`, 
bridged casting: `(__bridge void *)self; / (__bridge_retain void*) self`, `CFBridgingRelease(self)`

But all of that results in my app crashing.

How can I cast my `self` to `void*`? Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: Please add your code. The casting is fine so we should see the rest of the code to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a [bridged cast](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#bridged-casts) with no transfer of ownership is enough:

```
@implementation Foo

- (void)bar
{
  void *ctx = (__bridge void *) self;

  dosmthg(callback, ctx);
}

@end

static void
callback(void *ctx)
{
  Foo *foo = (__bridge Foo *) ctx;

  /* ... */
}
```